# Spring JNDI property place holder in weblogic

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jndi

How can I configure JNDI settings to read external properties file while startup in Weblogic?

for example in tomcat we mention it in context.xml and in JBoss its under standalone-full.xml which uses naming subsystem.

**Tomcat context.xml**

```
<Environment name="jndi/properties" value="/dummy/dummy.properties" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

**JBoss standalone-full.xml**

```
<bindings>
    <simple name="java:/comp/env/jndi/dummy" value="/dummy/dummy.properties" type="java.lang.String"/>
</bindings>
```

Similar way how can I define in weblogic?

Comment: Take a look at this:
https://phillipgreenii.github.io/specifying-projectstage-in-jndi-with/